# Audio streaming issues on smart phones

Tags: audio-streaming, smartphone

I am developing an audio streaming site (For an FM Channel). The site has two version one for web and another for mobile device. I faced issues on mobile device the API is not playing in smart phone. The site works perfectly. But on mobile its not playing, when I try with mobile simulators or safari developer option setting user agent as iphone, it was working but taking too long to play. I'm using FLASH-TDPlayerAPI1.0 for audio streaming. I am not creating a native app for mobile I'm using mobile version of the site.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the best way to support streaming audio on mobile devices is to let the native player handle it.  While your page won't be visible when this happens, you won't have to worry about the poor compatibility for Flash/HTML5.  In a couple years this won't be an issue, but for now, this is the only way to ensure something is going to work the way you want.

### Android

Link to the actual MP3 stream itself.  When the link is clicked, the browser will make a request for the stream to determine its content type.  When it sees something like `audio/mpeg`, it will launch the native audio player to play the stream.

### iOS, Blackberry, Palm, etc.

Link to an M3U playlist file that contains the stream URL.  This can be a simple one-line text file that has the URL in it.  When the link is clicked, the native player will open the playlist and begin streaming the audio.